# Referer does not send when playing HLS videos in Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, video.js

The HLS streaming files are composed by 1 .m3u8 file and N .ts files.

We use the videojs to play the HLS streaming files. The referer header will only be sent for .m3u8 file and will not be sent in reading .ts files in Chrome of Android.

I have the referer check to prevent the hotlinking when users access the .m3u8 and .ts files, but it will be broken in Chrome of Android.

Is there any approach to send the referer header for .ts files in Android Chrome?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not with Android's native HLS playback but if you use videojs-contrib-hls to play HLS the header will be set: https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls#overridenative